# MySQL Workbench EER diagram creation

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

There are two issues here regarding MySQL Workbench.

Is there a way to update an existing EER diagram with newly created DB tables, so that the EER diagrams automatically reflects the new tables AND their relationships.

OR

Is there a way to auto create the relationships between the table while creating a new EER diagram from an existing database?

I have about 70 tables in an existing database. So creating the relationship links between every table might be quite time consuming and not very productive.

If none of the above is possible, is there any tool out there which would allow me to create an EER diagram with all the relationship paths in place with in the diagram from an existing database.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [designer feature of phpmyadmin (version 2.10.0 or newer)](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/relation#Designer). It automatically does what you want.

Although my MySql-workbench does automatically creates relationship.

If you can upload the db-dump it would be helpful.

Are you using innodb or MyIASM?